# Gnome session log getting too large

Tags: gnome-terminal, upstart

Under my user a hidden system folder `.cache/upstart/` is getting insanely large - 99G. This is mainly due to a file `gnome-session.log`. Does anybody know what this folder is and why it may get so large? Can I safely remove the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a log, so yes, you can safely remove this file.

Comment: I would also like to understand what is growing so much this file - it seems full of log of this error             kbuildsycoca4(21468) KBuildServiceFactory::populateServiceTypes: "/usr/share/applications/shotwell-viewer.desktop" specifies undefined mimetype/servicetype "image/x-mrw"

Comment: I don't know, however there is a bug on Launchpad which describe similar situation. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/1269838 Maybe there you will be able to find solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem also, *gnome-session-Unity.log* file was getting large.

Before this I installed the *scratch* programming environment, this programm has the *squeak-vm* dependencies also installed 1st time on this machine. The *squeak-vm* was locked on the launcher, the line in the *gnome-session-Unity* log file

```
    (zenity:3190): GLib-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.40.2/./glib/giounix.c:410Error while getting flags for FD: Bad file descriptor (9)
```

this entry was repeated and the file getting bigger.

Also a window from squeak-vm was opened and couldn't normally close that window.

In order to solve the problem I uninstalled the *scratch* package and the *squeak-vm* package, close the window from squeak-vm with *xkill*.

Environment: Ubuntu 14.04 , scratch 1.4.0.6~dfsg1-5, squeak-vm 1:4.10.2.2614-1ubuntu2, zenity 3.8.0-1ubuntu1